# Servers for web service

Tags: java, web-services

I heard about some servers such as GlassFish, but I am not sure what server is best for a Java based web service.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "best" webserver, it all depends on your requirements.

Some popular AS:

- Jetty
- Tomcat
- JBoss
- TomEE
- Weblogic
- Websphere Application Server

Depending on what you're doing the AS might also change.
For local development Jetty might be fine, but for your acceptance etc you might want Tomcat.